# How to find the amount of time taken during Iterative loop?

Tags: bash, shell

Trying to subtract two times down to the nanosecond in shell.

```
declare start

function handler() {
count=$1

if [ "$1" -le 0 ]; then
  echo "Not a valid entry"
  exit
  fi

  read -p "Enter in R or N: " VAR1
  VAR2="R"
  VAR3="r"
  VAR4="N"
  VAR5="n"

  date +"%A %B %d, %Y %T.%N"
  start=$(date +"%T.%N")
  if [ "$VAR1" = "$VAR2" ]; then
    recFib "$1" "$start"
  elif [ "$VAR1" = "$VAR3" ]; then
    recFib "$1" "$start"
  elif [ "$VAR1" = "$VAR4" ]; then
    itFib "$1" "$start"
  elif [ "$VAR1" = "$VAR5" ]; then
    itFib "$1" "$start"
  else
    echo "Not a valid input"
  fi

}

function recFib() {

  if [ $1 -le 0 ]; then
    echo 0
  elif [ $1 -eq 1 ]; then
    echo 1
  else
    stop=$(date +"%T.%N")
    echo $((date $stop-$start))
    echo $(($(recFib $(($1 - 2))) + $(recFib $(($1 - 1)))))
  fi

}
```

I have tried this a number of different ways however I am not sure how to perform the subtraction on the two times. Since it is recursive I am trying to grab the time after each generation.

Answer (score 1):

You must use something that supports floating point math. You can use `bc` or you can use `awk`. For example, let's say you have a start and end time of:

```
01:39:47.109964128
01:43:07.280513101
```

To get the time difference, you can simply pipe the two times to `awk` on separate lines. Below with the start time first and stop time second, e.g.:

```sh
$ echo -e "01:39:47.109964128\n01:43:07.280513101" |
awk -F: '
  FNR==1 {h1=$1; m1=$2; s1=$3; next} 
  {h2=$1; m2=$2; s2=$3; exit} 
  END { 
    if (s2 < s1) {s2 += 60; m2 -= 1} 
    printf "%02d:%02d:%012.9f\n", h2-h1, m2-m1, s2-s1 }
'
00:03:20.170548973
```

Where `h1`, `m1`, `s1` are hour-start, minute-start, seconds-start, etc....

---

For a solution with date, you have to convert both start time and stop time to seconds since epoch, e.g. `'+%s.%N'` and then pipe the subtraction of seconds.nanoseconds to `bc` and then you need to convert back to `H:M:S.N` format.

Comment: well …. "You must use something that supports floating point math" …. technically doesn't *have* to be …. you can artificially take out the decimal points from them (as long as both inputs are aligned ), operate as if big integers (and make it into high/low buckets if it's too big, then place the dot back later. even a 48-bit unsigned integer is wide enough to handle 72 hours total width of time-diff calculation at nanosec precision. that said, if the constraint being placed is 32-bit unsigned type, then yes nanosec precision is barely 4.29 seconds of it

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto - right you are, but then that puts all the onus on you to check the difference between start and end time and to adjust (borrow and carry) in the event the end nano-seconds are less than start. Just much easier using `bc` or `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
start=$(date +%s.%N)
stop=$(date +%s.%N)
```

Using only `%s` and `%N` is timezone independent (like `-u`). So hazards on summer time switch are suppressed.

To get the difference, use:

```
duration=$( bc <<<"$stop-$start" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not move

```
stop=$(date +"%T.%N")
echo $((date $stop-$start))
```

to the end of `function handler()` body.